Php Laravel PhpUnit Test Returns 404 error
My test result always return 404 but i define route for api.
why like this? i cannot find any solution.
my test function :
public function test_can_update_integration()
{

    $integrationArr = ['hepsiburada', 'getir', 'trendyol'];
    $index = rand(0 , count($integrationArr) -1);

    $data = [
        'integration' => $integrationArr[$index],
        'username' => $this->faker->word,
        'password' => $this->faker->word,
        'id' => 1
    ];

    Passport::actingAs(
        User::factory()->create()
    );

    $response = $this->putJson(route('integration.edit'), $data);

    $response->assertStatus(201);
}

my api route:
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function(){

 Route::group(['prefix' => 'integration'], function () {
    Route::get('/list', [IntegrationController::class, 'list'])->name('integration.list');
    Route::post('/store', [IntegrationController::class, 'store'])->name('integration.store');
    Route::put('/update', [IntegrationController::class, 'update'])->name('integration.edit');
    Route::delete('/delete', [IntegrationController::class, 'delete'])->name('integration.del');
 });
});


You should show the code from your IntegrationController@update method.
You might be using something like Integration::findOrFail(...) Which could throw a 404 if you did not create the record first.

I am not sure, but if you have a route group with prefix, you do not have to add extra / to your routes below.
Instead of Route::put('/update', ... add Route::put('update', ...
The second issue can be a middleware. I don't see any login in your test, so it can prevent using the routes in the authenticated group.
As I check your code, don't you want to store the data instead of update?
I hope it helps

Adding / or not makes no difference, I personally always add them, because I had issue in the past because of not adding them, but I am not sure about the current state. The author is login in, Passport::actingAs
